# Plant recommendation for a home office

Tags: plant-recommendations, office-gardening

I am looking for a plant recommendation for a home office. I would like it to be 'interesting' - which rules out most of the typical office plants like spider plants, mother-in-law's tongue, etc.

The location is a north facing window. This is Texas so outside light is fairly bright, but of course north isn't direct.

I have a thermometer/humidity meter, so the temperature is usually 80-82F but can range from about 70F (when I have the window open) up to about 85F.

With a/c and computers the humidity is low. As I type this it is 31% - no doubt it will go up with tonight's rain. Over winter it was below 20% for an extended period.

A local nursery has some nice hibiscus but from what I've read, the dry air would be a problem.

I have a small grow lamp if need be.

As I type this, I've just thought of trying my hand at cacti again. I've had mixed results with indoor types in the past though - usually because you don't know they're sick/stressed until it is too late.

Comment: Nice to hear from you again, drop by more often

Comment: have you looked into a dwarfing citrus tree, or a morenga (bonsai it)?

Comment: I think citrus also usually likes a lot of light? I tend to also think of indoor citrus needing a lot of space, but as you say maybe there's a very dwarf plant.

Comment: A local high school career center have some kind of biology/horticultural program, and had a plant sale today. So we went. Pouring rain outside, but I bought some small cacti and succulents. The plan is to get a shallow pot & sand/etc in the next few days and re-pot them all together.  I think simply writing the question above gave me the idea of cacti! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Many Araceae with thick leaves would suit your environment: **zamioculcas, monstera**. They grow quite big and don’t care about humidity. Zamioculcas is my favourite for being chubby and easily surviving 2 week holidays without watering.

Forest cacti are a good choice: check **epiphyllum (orchid cactus)**. Desert cacti would need some more sun than you have.

**African violets** love northern windows, and there are many colourful species.

As for snake plant, there are more exotic varieties, that still have the hardiness of the original plant. Check **sansevieria spaghetti**.

Several orchids are completely OK with dry air: **haemaria/ludisia** has beautiful leaves and **phalaenopsis** flowers.

Ficus varieties with dark leaves will also be happy.

If you like to experiment, check **ivy plants**. You can make them climb a basket, wall or any surface. They are also resistant to shadow and dry air.

Comment: Thanks. I thought African violets needed humidity? I've had mixed results with orchids in the past although they are of course extremely diverse - I'll look at the ones you mention. Also the epiphyllum and araceae.